# multiple tables for distinct queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Originally my sql query works to check if there is pending timesheet/overtime ready for manager to review... now i added in on-call timesheets which is on a different table...

my previous sql query that worked but WITHOUT $ONCALL_TABLE...

```
list($qh, $num) = dbQuery("SELECT manager FROM $USER_TABLE WHERE username IN (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM $TIMES_TABLE WHERE submitstatus=1 OR ot_status=1)");
```

---

now im trying to add the pending on-call timesheet to the same sql query but i keep getting errors... maybe someone can help me fix my syntax?:

```
list($qh, $num) = dbQuery("SELECT manager FROM $USER_TABLE WHERE username IN (SELECT DISTINCT $TIMES_TABLE.uid, $ONCALL_TABLE.uid FROM $TIMES_TABLE, $ONCALL_TABLE WHERE $TIMES_TABLE.submitstatus=1 OR $TIMES_TABLE.ot_status=1 OR $ONCALL_TABLE.submitstatus=1)");
```

ERROR I GET:
Can't perform query: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: What errors are you getting?  That would help a _lot_.

Comment: sorry i forgot the error.. i added it to the post now.

Comment: can you state what are the tables involved? what are the relationship between each tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the subquery, but I would handle it using a `union all`:

```
SELECT manager
FROM $USER_TABLE
WHERE username IN (SELECT uid
                   from (select $TIMES_TABLE.uid
                         from $TIMES_TABLE
                         where $TIMES_TABLE.submitstatus=1 OR $TIMES_TABLE.ot_status=1
                         union all
                         select $ONCALL_TABLE.uid
                         from $ONCALL_TABLE
                         where $ONCALL_TABLE.submitstatus=1
                        ) t
                   )
```

To be honest, though, the `union all` may interfere with with the use of indexes.  This might perform better:

```
SELECT manager
FROM $USER_TABLE
WHERE username IN (select $TIMES_TABLE.uid
                   from $TIMES_TABLE
                   where $TIMES_TABLE.submitstatus=1 OR $TIMES_TABLE.ot_status=1
                  ) or
      username in (select $ONCALL_TABLE.uid
                   from $ONCALL_TABLE
                   where $ONCALL_TABLE.submitstatus=1
                  )
```

Comment: yes i used the second one you posted and it works! thanks gordon and  Infiltrator for all the help!